# Hacer que el texto de un EditView cambie según un valor que haya almacenado

Tags: java, android, xml

En mi app de android tengo un EditText en el que e puede introducir un ID. Para evitar que se meta otro y que el usuario sepa cuál es el que está metido, me gustaría cambiar el texto que tiene("escribe tu ID") por el ID en sí (por ejemplo, que ponga "33241" en ese hueco) cuando almacene un ID. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardarte el ID en el sharedPreferences cuando lo tengas:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("user_id", uID);
editor.commit();
```

Cuando muestres la pantalla con el EditText lo recoges del Shared:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String uID = sharedPref.getString("user_id","escribe tu ID");
```

Y luego lo seteas en el EditText; ya sea en el PlaceHolder/Hint si quieres editarlo o como setText y pones Disabled el EditText.

```
edtText.setHint(uID);
edtText.setText(uID);
```

Te recomiendo que trabajes con el id como String; puedes guardartelo como Integer/Long pero a la hora de hacer un setText/setHint si pones un tipo numerico Android interpretará que quieres cogerlo de un strings.xml; un truquillo sería:

```
int nID = 2;
edtText.setHint(""+nID);
```